# jquery if statements dependent on current url

Tags: jquery, string, url

I have a scenario where i want button colors to change depending on the page. I have the animation working with one default color and an array of other colors.

What i want to do though is when i am on the 'red' page to change the default(which is 'blue') to 'red'.

I know i can do this with if statements, but i want to compare it to the url. I dont know how to get the url and then store it. I know the exact pages that i can compare the url to, but i would also like it to work with sibling pages of that main.

I just dont know how to get the url with jquery, test against it, and test for siblings of the KNOWN urls.

```
 EXAMPLE:
    foobar.com <- 'blue'
    foobar.com/red/ <- 'red'
    foobar.com/red/car <- still 'red'
    foober.com/green/ <- 'green'



var urlRed = "foobar.com/red/"
var urlGreen ="foobar.com/green/"
var urlInput = ??

if(urlInput == urlRed){
   ...set default to red...
} else if( urlInput == urlGreen ){
      ...set default to green...
} else {
   ...set default to blue...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];

switch(url){
    case "red": // set default to red   
    break;

    case "green": //set default to green;
    break;

    default: // set to blue (default)
}
```

Comment: Does this test for sibling pages to /red/? like /red/car/ ?

Comment: So i tried it and it works for this scenario but for my exact situation the url starts after the second slash.

so my urls look like so foobar.com/blank/red/ 
foobar.com/blank/red/car foobar.com/blank/green/

this doesnt seem to work for it in the case. i tried to change the number to '2', but that didnt work.

Comment: weird, i changed it to 2 and it did work, try alert(url); and see what you are getting..

Comment: nevermind, it works great. thanks. i think the first time it didnt reload the new js file and was still using the old one. Thanks! u win :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    var red = "red";
    var green = "green";
    var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

    if(url.indexOf(red) >= 0){
       ...set default to red...
    } else if( url.indexOf(green) >= 0 ){
          ...set default to green...
    } else {
       ...set default to blue...
    }
}
```

Comment: does this mean ANY instance of the word red will trigger the change in color?

Comment: As posted, yes but it can be customized. Even regEx can be used if needed. For example instead of using var red = "red", we could use var red = ".com/red".

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL in Jquery using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
});
```

or

```
$(location).attr('href');
```